# Making a Text object to a grease object with Python

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I would like to convert an existing text object to a grease object. Meaning that the text is a path with a grease material. All with Python.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Using

```
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')
```

Does not fill the holes:

[image]

After conversion:

[image]

Scene file is [here](https://we.tl/t-Aop6CUUVE5).

Comment: does 'bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')' work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you go under *Scripting* tab and right click the text object then choose *Convert To > Grease Pencil*, you will see in the [`Info Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info_editor.html) that the equivalent code is `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')`

So you can run the following script when your text object is selected:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='GPENCIL')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove as answers, since it makes holes in the text.. Might just be me but I can't get this to work.